# Máscara personalizada não funciona no jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Preciso inserir uma máscara de telefone, CPF, CNPJ em algumas colunas do jqGrid, mas ele não funciona de jeito nenhum!!!

Já segui o exemplo na [documentação](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter), verifiquei em [vários sites](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/doc/_2v70w5p2k.htm) e nada.

Alguém sabe como implementar isso? Estou a 1 semana parado com esse problema, não é possível ser tão difícil fazer algo tão simples no JQuery!!! (Desculpem o desabafo)

A versão do JQuery que uso é 1.11.93, a versão do jqGrid é 4.5.4

Abaixo está o meu código:

```
this.montarGRID = function (p_gridName, p_dados, p_header, p_descriptor, p_contentName, p_primaryKey, p_filtroGrid) {
jQuery("#" + p_gridName).jqGrid( {
    data : p_dados, 
    datatype : "local", 
    sortable : true, 
    colNames : p_header, 
    colModel : p_descriptor, 
    rowNum : 30, 
    rowList : [30, 50, 100], 
    pager : '#p' + p_gridName, 
    recordpos : 'right', 
    viewrecords : true, 
    sortorder : "desc", 
    width: screen.availWidth - (screen.availWidth * 3 / 100),
    height : screen.availHeight - 250, 
    ignoreCase : true, 
    multiselect : false, 
    shrinkToFit : false, ...
};

function telefone(cellValue, opts, rowObject) {
    console.log("gri.locale-pt-br.js formatter telefone " + cellValue);
    return "Telefone: " + cellValue;
}
```

o modelo do colModel é

```
[
{formatter=integer, index=id, hidden=true, sortable=true, sorttype=integer, width=75, align=center, name=id}, 
{formatter=integer, index=VPD_GEMPI, search=false, hidden=true, sorttype=integer, sortable=true, width=0, align=right, name=VPD_GEMPI, editrules={number=true, required=true}, editable=true}, 
{formatter=date, formatoptions={srcformat=ISO8601Short, newformat=d/m/Y}, index=DT_DIGIT, search=true, hidden=false, sortable=true, width=0, align=right, name=DT_DIGIT, dateFormat=d/m/Y, editrules={required=true, date=true}, editable=true}, 
{formatter=email, index=EMAIL, search=true, hidden=false, sorttype=text, sortable=true, width=0, align=right, name=EMAIL, editrules={text=true, required=false}, editable=true}, 
{formatter=telefone, index=TELCONTATO01, search=true, hidden=false, sorttype=text, sortable=true, width=0, align=right, name=TELCONTATO01, editrules={text=true, required=false}, editable=true}, 
{formatter=telefone, index=TELCONTATO02, search=true, hidden=false, sorttype=text, sortable=true, width=0, align=right, name=TELCONTATO02, editrules={text=true, required=false}, editable=true} 
]
```

Um detalhe é que as máscaras padrão do jqGrid funcionam (integer, number, email, date)